# How to prevent maven release plugin from adding tag to pom?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm incorporating the maven release plugin into my projects and it works well, with one exception: whenever I run `release:prepare`, it modifies the pom by adding a tag inside the scm area, like this:

```
<scm>
    <connection>${project-home}</connection>
    <developerConnection>${project-home}</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

Is there any way to prevent it?

**Edit**

I found out that, according to [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-723), the tag is used for SCMs other than Subversion, since it is not included in the `connection`/`developerConnection` tags.

However, I don't know if the tag is just informational or if it is needed by the plugin. If it is just informational, I think there should be a way to not include it.

Comment: So what's the problem with that?

Comment: @khmarbaise It is not a problem, `release:prepare` runs just fine. Just wanted to know if there was a way to not include it.